# JHipster page blank

Tags: java, jhipster, gateway

Hi i have installed jhipster 4.1.1 and im trying to create microservice and gateway applications, im using jhipster-registry, the microservice start ok, the gateway start ok, but when im trying to load localhost:8080, i obtained blank page, and no error on log.
whats happen?

```
    Application 'clothes' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8080
    External:   http://192.168.56.1:8080
    Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
2017-04-06 11:15:17.186  INFO 6344 --- [  restartedMain] com.anelsoftware.clothes.ClothesApp      : 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Config Server:  Connected to the JHipster Registry config server!
----------------------------------------------------------
2017-04-06 11:19:58.930  INFO 6344 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

No entities were generated

Comment: did you run npm install or yarn install ?

Comment: no error in browser console?

Comment: yes, mvn clean install too

Comment: i dont have error in console

Comment: im trying npm install again and clear cache of chrome

Comment: i have blanck page :- (

Comment: chrome-extension://obkfjhifkbhimlocpddgamonjihinpak/go.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://obkfjhifkbhimlocpddgamonjihinpak/go.js:3
    at chrome-extension://obkfjhifkbhimlocpddgamonjihinpak/go.js:4
    at chrome-extension://obkfjhifkbhimlocpddgamonjihinpak/go.js:5

Comment: It's likely that the front end has not been "webpacked". Take a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51285405/3573553

Answer (score 1):

You have to install all dependency manager, package manager and build tools for successfully run the JHipster app ( mvn, nvm, npm, bower, gulp ) before "yo jhipster" process.

If you have choose not stable version of Angular on generating process you have to change it or regenerate app.

For start JHipster app correctly you have to start 1-BackEnd mvnw or gradlew and 2-FrontEnd => yarn start.

Comment: ok im triyng to install all, in a few minutes posto results, nvm whats is?

Comment: i have installed all mentioned tools and it worked! this was problem for me too :)). if problem is Angular, just consider that Angular is stable but with JHipster integration is not stable yet..

Comment: i select angular 2(beta) in gateway proyect.

Comment: But  if i run with yarn start in console and run SpringBootstap app from SpringToolSuite work perfectly

Comment: This was problem for me too, but in Ubuntu machines it is working perfectly:))

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the problem is Angular Beta, run gateway from springboot run and yarn start and works fine, now if only run springboot run does not work, any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I experience blank page when using MySQL on development.

The localhost:8080 is only for API request. With Angular, you access it on a different port.

Go to  `webpack.dev.js`

Change the port to 9060

```
plugins: [
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 9060, // change this into 9060
        proxy: {
            target: 'http://localhost:9060'
        }
    }, {
        reload: false
    }),
```

and then access it on localhost:9060

Answer (score 0):

I have found this with the latest JHipster (4.1.* and Angular 5).
My solution was to regenerate the application and everything worked.

Comment: By re-generating you ran a full frontend build, the real solution is the one from @Musa

Comment: Thanks @GaëlMarziou I was mostly concerned about being unable to generate the front-end at all.